# Are emails from the Necurs bot net DKIM and/or SPF signed?

Tags: spam, botnet, dkim, spf

As the questions title already asks: Are emails sent by Necurs DKIM and/or SPF signed?

Or are they unsigned and simply spoofed?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know necurs spam is spoofed and/or sent from infected machines acting as MTAs.

Other bot nets however obtain valid credentials which they then use for sending emails via the respective MTA which might - or might not - are DKIM signed and/or SPF controlled.